# Same crawled property for two different managed properties

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sharepoint, csom

I'm trying to customize the default item search display template:
1) first i have create managed properties for metadatas that i wanna display as a result of my search, and add them to my display template .
Example : for the column client name i have create a managed property "client name" and add to it the crawled property "ows_client_name" every thing work fine,my search result retrieve me the client name .
2) I add a refinement web-part to refine my search result , for that i have modified "RefinableString" and add to them crawled properties of metadatas that i want use as a refiners .
Example for "RefinableString00" i add the crawled property "ows_client_name" in ordre to refine client name . 
After adding "RefinableString00" the refiner work fine but i can't display the client name in my search result.

Can we use the same crawled property for two different managed properties?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use same crawled property for two different managed properties.

search API should contain

`&selectproperties=RefinableString00`  or `&selectproperties=client name`
to display the client name